# Kubernetes define timeout beetween two services with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, istio

I'm studying how Istio works and in particular I'm looking at timeouts.

I followed [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-timeouts/) guide provided by Istio Docs, where the following VirtualService gets defined:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
    timeout: 0.5s
```

If I understood well, every call to ratings service get a 0.5s timeout. I was wondering if it's possible to define timeout only in the communication beetween (for example) a pod and a service, and not for every call received by the service

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to istio and its configuration, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The [official istio discourse](https://discuss.istio.io/) might also a good place to ask such a question.